# algorithm2e package: "Missing { insterted although everything appears & compiles fine

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I get the following error while trying to compile a .tex that contains a pseudocode using algorithm2e package.

The error is the following:

> Missing { inserted.
>       
>       ^
>       l.412 }
>       A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
>       You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
>       so that I will find a matching right brace soon.

The code is the following:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]

 \KwIn{a data set X of $d$ features $S(F_1,F_2,...F_d$), class labels $C$ (classification) or target values $T$ (regression),  threshold $\delta$}
 \KwOut{optimal feature subset $S_{best}$ }
 \For{i =1 to d} {calculate $Corr_{i,T}$ \

 \If{$Corr_{i,T} \geq \delta $} {
 append $F_i$ to $S_{list}$ } }

 Order $S_{list}$ in descending order \

 $F_p$ = getFirstFeature($S_{list}$); \ 

\Repeat{$F_p$ == $\emptyset$}{

\If{$F_q$ != $\emptyset$}{ \Repeat{$F_q == \emptyset$} {${F^'}_q = F_q$ \

\If{$SU_{p,q} \geq SU_{q,T}$} { remove $F_q$ from $S_{list}$; \

$F_q$ = getNextFeature($S_{list}$,$F{^'}_q$);\

\Else{$F_q$ = getNextFeature($S_{list}$,$F_q$);} 

 } 

}
$F_p = getNextFeature(S_{list},F_p)$;
}


}
$S_{best}$ = $S_{list}$

 \

 \caption{FCBF outline for a regression problem}
\end{algorithm}
```

---

I have checked my code thoroughly, however it seems there are no braces error, or using mathmode words where I shouldn't. Also, everything compiles fine! 
Can someone point out what's wrong? It's really irritating because every time i compile something this error appears and I am auto-directed at that point of the document ....

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  to indicate that something is code, highlight it and then click on the icon that looks like open+close braces, above the answer box.  (i've done that here.)  it seems that double backslashes at the ends of lines get cut down to singles; i haven't touched those, but you can fix them -- you can always edit your own question.  also, exactly *what* was on line 412?  you haven';t given us enough of an example that we can reproduce the problem.  (a minimum example should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and produce the error you describe.)

Comment: The problem is a misplaced bracket that should be *before* the `\Else` but actually appears *after* the `\Else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `F^'`; `F'` suffices.

Here's an update of your code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e,amsmath}

\begin{document}    

\begin{algorithm}
  \KwIn{a data set X of~$d$ features $S(F_1, F_2, \dots, F_d$), 
    class labels~$C$ (classification) or target values~$T$ (regression), threshold~$\delta$}
  \KwOut{optimal feature subset~$S_{\text{best}}$}
  \For{$i = 1 \textbf{ to } d$}{
    calculate $\text{Corr}_{i,T}$\;
    \If{$\textup{Corr}_{i,T} \geq \delta$}{
      append~$F_i$ to~$S_{\text{list}}$\;
    }
  }
  Order~$S_{\text{list}}$ in descending order\;
  $F_p \leftarrow \text{getFirstFeature}(S_{\text{list}})$\;
  \Repeat{$F_p = \emptyset$}{
    \If{$F_q \neq \emptyset$}{
      \Repeat{$F_q = \emptyset$}{
        $F'_q \leftarrow F_q$\;
        \If{$\text{SU}_{p,q} \geq \text{SU}_{q,T}$}{
          remove~$F_q$ from~$S_{\text{list}}$\;
          $F_q \leftarrow \text{getNextFeature}(S_{\text{list}}, F'_q)$\;
        }
        \Else{
         $F_q \leftarrow \text{getNextFeature}(S_{\text{list}}, F_q)$\;
        }
      } 
    }
    $F_p \leftarrow \text{getNextFeature}(S_{\text{list}}, F_p)$\;
  }
  $S_{\text{best}} \leftarrow S_{\text{list}}$\;
 \caption{FCBF outline for a regression problem}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```